# How to Redirect the user to a specific page in the website if hes not logged in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, http-redirect

Title says it all, i want it so if the user tries to navigate to any page or access anything in the website to be redirected to a login page, that's only if hes not logged in.

This is my simple login code :

```
public ActionResult login(MvcMobile.Models.Users x)
    {
        var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.username == x.username && u.password == x.password);


    if (user == null)
        ModelState.AddModelError("","username or password is wrong.");

    else
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.username, false);
        Response.Redirect("/");
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

i tried to place this code in the main layout, but i got an infinite redirect loop :P

```
 @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                   {
          <p> Hi @User.Identity.Name</p>
                   }
                   else
                      {

                        Response.Redirect("~/home/login");
                    }
```

any idea ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decorate your controllers/actions with the `[Authorize]` attribute instead. Or if you want this to apply to all controllers add it as a global action filter:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Of course by doing this you might want to exclude your AccountController from authentication by decorating it with the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute:

Then in your web.config, set the `loginUrl` page of your forms authentication tag to point to the login page where all anonymous users will be redirected to:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/home/login" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Thanks but im still being redirected to the default login url, and whenever i run the application i get an error on the line "<authentication mode="Forms">" the error says " Unrecognized configuration section authentication." , any idea ?

Comment: Where did you put this section? Did you put it inside the `<system.web>` node? Please read the following article to better familiarize yourself with how Forms Authentication works in ASP.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

Comment: i just moved it there and i got this error : " It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Darin Dimitrov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20165066/952310), you should also config the [LoginUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.loginurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute at the Web.config file, for example:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="member_login.aspx"
    defaultUrl="index.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: How is this different from Darin's answer?

Comment: In fact Darin Dimitrov edited and added the config part later :-)